# The blood pressure when blood comes out of body

Tags: blood-pressure

Is there any certain amount of pressure difference between our blood pressure and barometric pressure when blood of our body begins to come out?

Answer (score 1):

Blood pressure is the pressure *above* barometric pressure.  When you pump up a blood pressure cuff, or a tire for that matter, you don't have a gauge with a line at 760 torr / mmHg; you're measuring the pressure relative to the air in the room.

Note that blood pressure is only 16% of normal atmospheric pressure.  Imagine what your blood pressure would be if you were the victim of explosive decompression in outer space!